# Test Linearity Assumption - Hayes PROCESS

Tags: regression, linearity

Before running the Hayes PROCESS for my moderated mediation, I would like to ensure first, that the linearity assumption is fulfilled.

However, at this point, I am not sure which variables need to be linear. Does the assumption only apply to the relationship between IV-DV? Or do I also need to include the Mediator & Moderator variable in the scatterplot-matrix to test for linearity?

Thanks!

(I saw in another thesis, that they included the mediator in the linearity test (=matrix scatterplot), so that's why I am asking)